# YTM different to zero rates on zero-coupon bonds and issues with settlement days on discounting in QuantLib Python

Tags: python, quantitative-finance, quantlib

I have bootstrapped the the yield curve using both zero-coupon bonds and fixed coupon bonds using the code below;

```
# Importing Libraries:
# The code imports necessary libraries:
# pandas for data manipulation, matplotlib.pyplot for plotting, and QuantLib (ql) for quantitative finance calculations.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Use the QuantLib or ORE Libraries
import QuantLib as ql

# Setting Evaluation Date:
# Sets the evaluation date to May 31, 2023, for all subsequent calculations.
today = ql.Date(21, ql.November, 2023)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = today

# Calendar and Day Count:
# Creates a calendar object for South Africa and specifies the day-count convention (Actual/365 Fixed)
calendar = ql.NullCalendar()
day_count = ql.Actual365Fixed()

# Settlement Days:
zero_coupon_settlement_days = 4
coupon_bond_settlement_days = 3

# Face Value
faceAmount = 100

data = [
    ('11-09-2023', '11-12-2023', 0, 99.524, zero_coupon_settlement_days),
    ('11-09-2023', '11-03-2024', 0, 96.539, zero_coupon_settlement_days),
    ('11-09-2023', '10-06-2024', 0, 93.552, zero_coupon_settlement_days),
    ('11-09-2023', '09-09-2024', 0, 89.510, zero_coupon_settlement_days),
    ('22-08-2022', '22-08-2024', 9.0, 96.406933, coupon_bond_settlement_days),
    ('27-06-2022', '27-06-2025', 10.0, 88.567570, coupon_bond_settlement_days),
    ('27-06-2022', '27-06-2027', 11.0, 71.363073, coupon_bond_settlement_days),
    ('22-08-2022', '22-08-2029', 12.0, 62.911623, coupon_bond_settlement_days),
    ('27-06-2022', '27-06-2032', 13.0, 55.976845, coupon_bond_settlement_days),
    ('22-08-2022', '22-08-2037', 14.0, 52.656596, coupon_bond_settlement_days)]

helpers = []

for issue_date, maturity, coupon, price, settlement_days in data:
    price = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(price))
    today = ql.Date(21, ql.November, 2023)
    issue_date = ql.Date(issue_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
    maturity = ql.Date(maturity, '%d-%m-%Y')
    schedule = ql.Schedule(today, maturity, ql.Period(ql.Semiannual), calendar, ql.DateGeneration.Backward,
                           ql.Following, ql.DateGeneration.Backward, False)
    helper = ql.FixedRateBondHelper(price, settlement_days, faceAmount, schedule, [coupon / 100], day_count,
                                    False)
    helpers.append(helper)

curve = ql.PiecewiseCubicZero(today, helpers, day_count)

# Enable Extrapolation:
# This line enables extrapolation for the yield curve.
# Extrapolation allows the curve to provide interest rates or rates beyond the observed data points,
# which can be useful for pricing or risk management purposes.
curve.enableExtrapolation()

# Zero Rate and Discount Rate Calculation:
# Calculates and prints the zero rate and discount rate at a specific
# future date (May 28, 2048) using the constructed yield curve.
date = ql.Date(11, ql.December, 2023)
zero_rate = curve.zeroRate(date, day_count, ql.Annual).rate()
forward_rate = curve.forwardRate(date, date + ql.Period(1, ql.Years), day_count, ql.Annual).rate()
discount_rate = curve.discount(date)
print("Zero rate as at 28.05.2048: " + str(round(zero_rate*100, 4)) + str("%"))
print("Forward rate as at 28.05.2048: " + str(round(forward_rate*100, 4)) + str("%"))
print("Discount factor as at 28.05.2048: " + str(round(discount_rate, 4)))

# Print the Zero Rates, Forward Rates and Discount Factors at node dates
# print(pd.DataFrame(curve.nodes()))
node_data = {'Date': [],
             'Zero Rates': [],
             'Forward Rates': [],
             'Discount Factors': []}

for dt in curve.dates():
    node_data['Date'].append(dt)
    node_data['Zero Rates'].append(curve.zeroRate(dt, day_count, ql.Annual).rate())
    node_data['Forward Rates'].append(curve.forwardRate(dt, dt + ql.Period(1, ql.Years), day_count, ql.Annual).rate())
    node_data['Discount Factors'].append(curve.discount(dt))

node_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(node_data)

print(node_dataframe)

node_dataframe.to_excel('NodeRates.xlsx')

# Printing Daily Zero Rates:
# Prints the daily zero rates from the current date (May 31, 2023) to a maturity date that is 30
# years later. It calculates and prints the zero rates for each year using the constructed yield curve.
maturity_date = calendar.advance(today, ql.Period(1, ql.Years))
current_date = today
while current_date <= maturity_date:
    zero_rate = curve.zeroRate(current_date, day_count, ql.Annual).rate()
    print(f"Date: {current_date}, Zero Rate: {zero_rate}")
    current_date = calendar.advance(current_date, ql.Period(1, ql.Years))

# Creating Curve Data for Plotting:
# Creates lists of curve dates, zero rates, and forward rates for plotting.
# It calculates both zero rates and forward rates for each year up to 25 years from the current date.
                'Zero Rate': [],
                'Discount Factor': [],
                'Clean Price': [],
                'Dirty Price': []}

# Calculate bond prices and yields
for issue_date, maturity, coupon, price, settlement_days in data:
    price = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(price))
    today = ql.Date(21, ql.November, 2023)
    issue_date = ql.Date(issue_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
    maturity = ql.Date(maturity, '%d-%m-%Y')
    schedule = ql.Schedule(today, maturity, ql.Period(ql.Semiannual), calendar, ql.DateGeneration.Backward,
                           ql.Following, ql.DateGeneration.Backward, False)
    bondEngine = ql.DiscountingBondEngine(ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(curve))
    bond = ql.FixedRateBond(settlement_days, faceAmount, schedule, [coupon / 100], day_count)
    bond.setPricingEngine(bondEngine)

    # Calculate bond yield, clean price, and dirty price
    bondYield = bond.bondYield(day_count, ql.Compounded, ql.Annual)
    bondCleanPrice = bond.cleanPrice()
    bondDirtyPrice = bond.dirtyPrice()
    zero_rate = curve.zeroRate(maturity, day_count, ql.Annual).rate()
    discount_factor = curve.discount(maturity)

    # Append the results to the DataFrame
    bond_results['Issue Date'].append(issue_date)
    bond_results['Maturity Date'].append(maturity)
    bond_results['Coupon Rate'].append(coupon)
    bond_results['Price'].append(price.value())
    bond_results['Settlement Days'].append(settlement_days)
    bond_results['Yield'].append(bondYield)
    bond_results['Zero Rate'].append(zero_rate)
    bond_results['Discount Factor'].append(discount_factor)
    bond_results['Clean Price'].append(bondCleanPrice)
    bond_results['Dirty Price'].append(bondDirtyPrice)

# Create a DataFrame from the bond results
bond_results_df = pd.DataFrame(bond_results)

# Print the results
print(bond_results_df)

bond_results_df.to_excel('BondResults.xlsx')
```

I have the following questions or queries;
(i) The yield to maturity that I am getting for the first 4 zero-coupon bonds is slightly different from the zero (or spot) rates. My expectation is that the yield to maturity (YTM) and the zero rates for the first 4 zero-coupon bonds should be the same. What is causing the slight differences and how can I resolve this?
(ii) In trying to manually calculate the prices of the first 4 zero-coupon bonds by simply discounting the face amount of 100 using the YTM (which should be similar to zero rates) and the accrual period, I have noted that I need to adjust for the settlement days (T+4) in this case 4 days for the zero coupon bonds. My understanding of settlement days is that in this case the bond is settled 4 days after maturity hence this will increase the accrual period (or discounting period) by 4 days. Surprisingly, to get to the same price for the zero-coupon bonds, I have noticed that I have reduced the accrual period by 4 days instead of increasing. Am I missing something or this is not correct.

The final results will be in the BondResults.xlsx workbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 settlement days means that, if I buy the bond from you today, I won't get it right away but in 4 business days.  As you have seen, this decreases the discounting period; you need to discount not from maturity to today, but from maturity to 4 days from today.

As for zero-rate vs yield for zero-coupon bonds: the yield is calculated from the settlement date to the maturity, while the zero rate returned from the curve is from today to maturity.  If you write:

```
zero_rate = curve.forwardRate(bond.settlementDate(), maturity,
                              day_count, ql.Compounded, ql.Annual).rate()
```

you'll get the same numbers.

One thing: you're calling in a couple of places

```
curve.zeroRate(maturity, day_count, ql.Annual).rate()
```

but it should be

```
curve.zeroRate(maturity, day_count, ql.Compounded, ql.Annual).rate()
```

In this particular case, it worked because `ql.Annual` and `ql.Compounded` both happened to have value 1 and because `ql.Annual` is the default for the frequency you weren't passing.

Comment: Thanks Luigi, I was confusing myself from taking the maturity date as my reference point instead of taking the trade date. And for my second question, why is the zero rate slightly different from the YTM for zero-coupon bonds? Are these not supposed to be exactly the same?

Comment: Answer updated.